# Можно ли употребить "катапультировать" в значении переместить, перенести?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

> Архив в своё время (приблизительно в конце восьмидесятых) переезжал.
>   Документы оказались в беспорядке и всё ещё находились в стадии
>   разбора. Оттого меня вечно катапультирует. Из какого-нибудь
>   Темрюкского района Краснодарского края, где расположены
>   неисследованные памятники античного времени, – в Минусинск с планами
>   города и отдельно взятыми паспортами по каждому памятному для истории
>   месту. Или вдруг, бывает, вынесет меня к бюсту доярки-ударницы, кстати
>   превосходному (!), в крошечной деревне Черниговской области...

Comment: Автор пишет от имени авиатора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Катапульта** в общем случае – это метательная машина. Первые в истории катапульты начали применять еще до нашей эры в Греции (в V веке), затем вплоть до XV века их использовали во всех странах Европы. В «авиационном» значении слово ***катапульта*** заимств. в начале XX в. из англ. яз.

***Катапультировать*** –  термин относится **к авиации**.

Соответственно, можно использовать это слово в переносном значении (бросает, швыряет), но надо поставить **кавычки**: ***Оттого меня вечно "катапультирует".***

**КАТАПУЛЬТА**, -ы; ж. [лат. catapulta от греч. kata- – вниз и pallein – швырять] 1. Ист. **Осадная машина** для метания камней, бочек с горящей смолой и т.п., применявшаяся в древности при осаде городов.  3. Устройство для автоматического выбрасывания из **летательного аппарата** с последующим спуском его на парашюте.

КАТАПУЛЬТИРОВАТЬ, св. и нсв. 1. кого-что. Выбросить - выбрасывать **из летательного аппарата** с помощью катапульты (3 зн.).

Answer (score 0):

В качестве авторской лексики, думаю, можно стерпеть.

Но более идиоматично в этом смысле звучали бы глаголы **швыряет, шарахает**.